# java actionlistener on a tab

Tags: java, actionlistener, jtabbedpane

Is it possible to put an actionlistener on a tab in swing? If it is please could you post a small example?

Comment: What do you need exactly.  Do you want the action to fire if a tab is switched?

Comment: I think a little search is more helpful then asking here. Ask here when you cannot find a solution for the problem. Please.

Comment: I have tryed to find a solution elsewhere but have not found anything that is the reason why I asked the question.

Comment: well, check [JTabbedPane](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) and [ChangeListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do that is to add a `javax.swing.event.ChangeListener` to the JTabbedPane itself.  You might have to keep track of the selected tab vs. previously selected tab depending on what you are doing with the state change...