# In Java how do you trap the event before the new JTab is switched to?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtabbedpane

how do you trap the event before the new tab is switched to?
In every Tab I have JTable and i do something with it's data(delete, add , update). I would like to do data validation(save or cancel changes) before switching to the new tab. I use Java 1.5.

```
class ViewPanel extends JPanel 
  {

    private void Components() {
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 400));

    tabbedPane.addTab("DC", ANSFER.getIcon(),new DcTabPanel(this), "DC");
    tabbedPane.addTab("PC", THUMB4.getIcon(),new PcTabPanel(this), "PC");

    tabbedPane.addChangeListener(this);
    add(tabbedPane);
     }


     public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

     }

   }
```

Comment: I am not really sure I understand your question. You need to be more specific.

Comment: @Vipar The OP wants to detect when a tab would be changed in a `JTabbedPane` *before* it actually happens.

Comment: Yes Indeed i want to prevent to be happens if the condition is not OK or let be happens but do some staff like save a data ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[JTabbedPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html) is backed by a [SingleSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SingleSelectionModel.html). If you extend [DefaultSingleSelectionModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultSingleSelectionModel.html), you can override the setSelectedIndex method and implement your logic.

```
// in new selection model:
public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
    // do pre-switch things here
    super.setSelectedIndex(index);
}

// in ViewPanel, on tabbedPane create:
tabbedPane.setModel(newSelectionModel);
```

The reason you can't simply use a ChangeListener is because that fires *on change*. By extending the selection model, you fire *before* the tab change.

Answer (score 4):

You can prevent tab switching by extending JTabbedPane and override `setSelectedIndex(int)`. Here is a small example illustrating that. It simply prevents from switching between non-contiguous tabs:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Test2 {
    private static class BlockingTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane {

        public static interface TabSwitchAllower {
            public boolean allowTabSwitch(int from, int to);
        }

        private TabSwitchAllower allower;

        public BlockingTabbedPane(TabSwitchAllower allower) {
            super();
            this.allower = allower;
        }

        @Override
        public void setSelectedIndex(int index) {
            if (allower == null || allower.allowTabSwitch(getSelectedIndex(), index)) {
                super.setSelectedIndex(index);
            }
        }

    }

    protected static void initUI() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        BlockingTabbedPane.TabSwitchAllower allower = new BlockingTabbedPane.TabSwitchAllower() {

            @Override
            public boolean allowTabSwitch(int from, int to) {
                if (Math.abs(from - to) == 1) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "You can only switch between contiguous tabs");
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new BlockingTabbedPane(allower);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tabbedPane.addTab("Tab-" + i, new JLabel("Hello tab " + i));
        }
        frame.add(tabbedPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[java actionlistener on a tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443559/java-actionlistener-on-a-tab)

[How to Write a Change Listener (Oracle Docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/changelistener.html)

[JTabbedPane API (Oracle Docs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html)

Those two links should help you out. I haven't really worked with tabbedPanes, but I am assuming that the `getSelectedComponent()` will return the current selected tab. So you can have a handle to the `currentTab` which will be set during instantiation. Then you can have something like this.

```
class TabListener implements ChangeListener {
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {

        // Replace JSlider with whatever your tab's data type is
        JSlider source = (JSlider)e.getSource();

        // Use the 'currentTab' handle to do what you want.

        currentTab = getSelectedComponent();
        // I'm assuming that the 'selected component' by the time this stuff
        // runs is going to be the new selected tab.
    }
}
```

I am *not* too confident about my answer, but I certainly hope that this will point you towards the right direction! Please say if you need any clarification or anything! If I happen to discover anything that I think might be useful, I'll be certain to edit my answer!