# ActionLister on a Change of Tab in JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtabbedpane

I have the following GUI:

[image]

The problem is, the [Register LMS] button should only be displayed when I'm on the Flood Monitoring tab.

When I go to the User Registration tab, another button should display called [Register User]. Obviously when I get back to the Flood Monitoring tab, I would need my [Register LMS] button back.

I know how to hide Swing components via the `setVisible(false);` method, but I am not sure how to add the trigger (action listener) to the change of tabs and nothing else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443559/java-actionlistener-on-a-tab might help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding a [ChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ChangeListener.html) to the JTabbedPane, this is only called when the object changes state. i.e When the tab changes.

Comment: Thanks Quirliom, Is there a way to make it stop firing a change listener when the GUI loads?

Comment: Unfortunately, not as far as I know.

Comment: @Ciwan: don't add the listener until the GUI has already loaded. 1+ to this answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Well that's simple and something I totally didn't think of.